# Bug: "\fbox" is not correctly displayed in my browser if there is a "\tag" inside "\fbox"

Tags: bug, mathjax

##### Problem

Some formulas I write in `\fbox` are not displayed strictly for me. The box around the equation has shifted to the left.
For example, the equation
$$
\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \frac{1}{1 - x} \right] = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot x^{k - \alpha} \right] \tag{4}\\
\end{align*}
$}
$$
becomes this / looks like this:

[image]

(this formula is from my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4678041/1103878))

It's obvious that this shouldn't be the case... This always occurs when I write `\tag` inside `\fbox`. Other examples are e.g.:
$$
\begin{align*}
\fbox{$ a + b = c \tag{1}$}\\
\fbox{$ i^{2} = -1 \tag{2} $}\\
\fbox{$ i \in \mathbb{C} \tag{3} $}\\
\end{align*}
$$

[image]

$$
\begin{align*}
\fbox{$ \mathscr{B}\left( H \right)\\
q = w + x \cdot i + y \cdot j + z \cdot k \in \mathbb{H}\\
i^{2} = j^{2} = k^{2} = i \cdot j \cdot k = -1 \tag{5} $}\\
\end{align*}
$$

[image]

##### Browser

I'm using "Google Chrome" with "Version $112.0.5615.138$ (Offizieller Build) ($64$-Bit)" aka Google Chrome: version $112.0.5615.138$ (official build) ($64$-bit). The only extensions I use is an adblocker and an anti-virus program and the problem isn't with these, because it still shows up erroneously when I disable both.

Comment: This is fixed in version 3 (and version 4) of MathJax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking the tag out of the fbox works for me:
$$
\fbox{$
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \frac{1}{1 - x} \right] = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot x^{k - \alpha} \right]\\
\end{align*}
$}\tag{4}
$$

`\fbox{$`

`\begin{align*}`

`\operatorname{D_{x}^{\alpha}}\left[ \frac{1}{1 - x} \right] = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\infty}\left[ \frac{\Gamma\left( k + 1 \right)}{\Gamma\left( k - \alpha + 1 \right)} \cdot x^{k - \alpha} \right]\\`

`\end{align*}`

`$}\tag{4}`

$$
\begin{align*}
\fbox{$ \mathscr{B}\left( H \right)\\
q = w + x \cdot i + y \cdot j + z \cdot k \in \mathbb{H}\\
i^{2} = j^{2} = k^{2} = i \cdot j \cdot k = -1$}\\
\end{align*}\tag{5}
$$

`\begin{align*}`

`\fbox{$ \mathscr{B}\left( H \right)\\ q = w + x \cdot i + y \cdot j + z \cdot k \in \mathbb{H}\\ i^{2} = j^{2} = k^{2} = i \cdot j \cdot k = -1$}\\`

`\end{align*}\tag{5}`